# different result regarding order of precedence of operator in c

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I am complete new to c programming. i ran this code to try to understand the order of precedence in c programming-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float sum = 8 / 4 * 2;

    printf("\n the solution of the expression is  %f", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

for this code i am correcly getting the output 4.000000

however if i write the print statement as

```
printf("\n the solution of the expression is  %f", 8 / 4 * 2);
```

i am getting the output as 0.000000. can anyone tell why does it give me different output for the same expression?

Comment: Nothing to do with operator precedence. How could it be?

Comment: Raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum and it should tell you.

Comment: If it were "precedence", you would expect "1.0000", not "0.00000"... You have to pay attention to what the results are telling you.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `8 / 4 * 2` is an *integer* operation with an *integer* result.

The variable `sum` if a `float` variable, so its value will be a floating point value, which can be used together with the `%f` format specifier.

But when you use the expression directly in `printf` you attempt to print an `int` value using the mismatching `%f` specifier, which leads to *undefined behavior*.